# Binding DataGrid row to a mthod in the ViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, binding, datagrid

I got a DataGrid and I want to make a CRUD with it, it's Bound to an ObservableCollection in the ViewModel and I created in each row of it a Delete button, the problem is when I click the button the event is fired from the Model, not the ViewModel so I can't really access the Collection but only the Selected Object

this is my View:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="EmployeeDataGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Employees}">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="First Name" Binding="{Binding FirstName}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Last Name" Binding="{Binding LastName}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Date Of Birth" Binding="{Binding DateOfBirth}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Address" Binding="{Binding Address}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Salary" Binding="{Binding Salary}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Function" Binding="{Binding Function}"/>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Button Click="{Binding Path=Update_Click}">Update</Button>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Button >Delete</Button>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your ViewModel, create an ICommand property which is set to a command class that takes a parameter, such as [this one (MvvmLight)](https://github.com/lbugnion/mvvmlight/blob/master/GalaSoft.MvvmLight/GalaSoft.MvvmLight%20(PCL)/Command/RelayCommandGeneric.cs) - the parameter is an instance of your employee class.

You can the bind the button in your template like this

```
<Button Content="Update"
        Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.UpdateCommand,
                  RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}"
        CommandParameter="{Binding}" />
```

The CommandParameter binding passes in the employee item for that row of the DataGrid.

Answer (score 0):

Add a property to your model such as `public object Tag { get; set; }`.

When the row instance object is created assign a reference to the VM or whatever you are trying to get at into `Tag`. That way when the operation is running from the instance as mentioned, just de-reference `Tag` into the class reference needed and utilize what it is pointing to.